# Multi Layered Hashmap and Arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I was working on a java program that takes a string and splits it into different levels.

```
Map<String, ArrayList<Map<String, ArrayList<Map<String,Map<String, String>>>>>> courseInfoMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Map<String,ArrayList<Map<String,Map<String, String>>>>>>();
ArrayList<Map<String, ArrayList<Map<String,Map<String, String>>>>> courseNumList = new ArrayList<Map<String, ArrayList<Map<String,Map<String, String>>>>>();
Map<String, ArrayList<Map<String,Map<String, String>>>> courseNumTextbookMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Map<String,Map<String, String>>>>();
ArrayList<Map<String,Map<String, String>>> listOfTextbooks = new ArrayList<Map<String,Map<String,String>>>();

Map<String, Map<String, String>> textbookMap = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();
Map<String, String> isbnMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
```

Essentially,
I'm trying to have a course code --> list of course num --> course num (key) --> list of textbooks --> textbook --> isbn number(str) --> price

So because some course codes have multiple course numbers it points to an arraylist.

I have been adding stuff backwards, so loops within loops. Assuming I did not screw up there. I've been trying to loop through the elements in the same sort of way assuming they were probably added.

```
for(Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<Map<String, ArrayList<Map<String,Map<String, String>>>>>> entry : courseInfoMap.entrySet()){
        System.out.println(entry.getKey());// COURSE CODE

        for(int i = 0; i < entry.getValue().size();i++){//loops through arraylist of course numbers
            System.out.println("i("+i+" - " + entry.getValue().get(i));

            for(Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<Map<String,Map<String,String>>>> entry2 : entry.getValue().get(i).entrySet()){
                System.out.println("   " + entry2.getKey());
                // . . . and so on
```

This hasnt worked it just loops through everything. On each level.

My question is how do I navigate through a large number of hashmaps and/or is there a better way to do this.

Example:

```
AAAA
     100
        Name
        ###
        $$$

        Name
        ###     <-- different from past
        $$$
     200 
        Name
        ###
        $$$
  BBBB
      101
        Name
        ###
        $$$
```

Comment: Don't hurt yourself with so many nested levels. Encapsulate and structure your data in classes.

Answer (score 3):

This seems exceedingly complicated, and frankly if I had to maintain that I'd really not look forward to it. Off the top of my head there are several other approaches you could probably take...

**Use a relational database**

Either an in-memory database or something like mysql or postgresql. They are designed for this sort of thing - organizing data and allowing for ad-hoc queries.

**Put your data in Objects**

Instead of Maps and Lists, just create an object that defines most of it in one place. Store *that* object in the List or Map and search for what you need directly. If you don't have too much data, a brute-force uninindexed search probably won't be that bad in wall-clock time.

Comment: Thats true. I didnt see what was right in front of me (the Objects). Thanks.